# There is nothing displayed in my Angular App

Tags: html, angular, web, frontend

I'm new in web development and i am following this [tutorial](https://www.toptal.com/angular/angular-5-asp-net-core), and up til i before back-end code i tried to build it but there is nothing in the page, i tried ng serve and ng build (then served it to my local IIS). here are the codes

**index.html (build)**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>NewApp</title>
  <base href="/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
<script src="runtime-es2015.js" type="module"></script><script src="runtime-es5.js" nomodule defer></script><script src="polyfills-es5.js" nomodule defer></script><script src="polyfills-es2015.js" type="module"></script><script src="styles-es2015.js" type="module"></script><script src="styles-es5.js" nomodule defer></script><script src="vendor-es2015.js" type="module"></script><script src="vendor-es5.js" nomodule defer></script><script src="main-es2015.js" type="module"></script><script src="main-es5.js" nomodule defer></script></body>
</html>
```

**app-routing.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule, Component } from "@angular/core";
import { RouterModule,Routes } from '@angular/router';
import {AuthGuard} from './helpers/canActivateAuthGuard';
import { LoginComponent }   from './components/login/login.component';
import { LogoutComponent }   from './components/login/logout.component';
import { DashboardComponent }   from './components/dashboard/dashboard.component';
import { UsersComponent }      from './components/users/users.component';
import {AppComponent} from './layout/app.component'

const routes: Routes = [

  {path: '', redirectTo: '/dashboard', pathMatch: 'full', canActivate: [AuthGuard]},
  {path: 'login', component: LoginComponent},
  {path: 'logout', component: LogoutComponent},
  {path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent},
  {path: 'users', component: UsersComponent},

]
@NgModule({

  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]

})

export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import {MatButtonModule} from '@angular/material/button';
import {MatCheckboxModule} from '@angular/material/checkbox'
import {MatInputModule} from '@angular/material/input';
import {MatFormFieldModule} from '@angular/material/form-field';
import {MatSidenavModule, MatSidenav} from '@angular/material/sidenav';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import {HttpClientModule} from '@angular/common/http';

@NgModule({

  imports: [

    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatCheckboxModule,
    MatInputModule,
    MatFormFieldModule,
    MatSidenavModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule],
  })

  export class AppModule{}
```

**app.component.html**

```
<div *ngIf="authentication">
  <app-head></app-head>

  <button type="button" mat-button (click)="drawer.toggle()">

    Menu

  </button>

  <mat-drawer-container class="example-container" autosize>

    <mat-drawer #drawer class="example=sidenav" mode="slide">

      <app-left-panel></app-left-panel>

    </mat-drawer>

    <div>

      <router-outlet></router-outlet>

    </div>
  </mat-drawer-container>
</div>

<div *ngIf="!authentication"><app-login></app-login></div>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'new-app';
}
```

Comment: what output did `ng-serve` give

Comment: Nothing, same as how i used ng build

Comment: What errors are you getting in the browser console?

Comment: here is the console output, but maybe this is just a warning for the whole browser

DevTools failed to parse SourceMap: chrome-extension://gighmmpiobklfepjocnamgkkbiglidom/include.postload.js.map

Comment: Create a working Angular app: https://cli.angular.io/ and compare your project. See where you went wrong. This is how you learn.

Comment: thanks! ill try this and update the question if I solved it before finding the answer here in this thread.

Comment: @JaspherJanPasol Did you resolve the problem?

Answer (score 2):

Your AppComponent is never declared. You are missing the following in the AppModule

```
@NgModule({
declarations : [AppComponent],
bootstrap: [AppComponent],
imports: [ 
...
```

This should have been indicated in your browsers developer tools.

Comment: added it now in the app module, but still nothing

Comment: Did you also consider my latest edit and add the bootstrap property? I've checked your tutorial and it was also missing from the NgModule there. I assume you've just copied it which will not work.

Comment: After declaring the component you should get a more detailed error logging in your dev tools. You're also missing the Import of the CommonModule since ngIf is used in your AppComponent as well.

Comment: hello, i just added it, still nothing

Comment: Please provide the error message in your dev tools for further troubleshooting. Angular will clearly point this out. You may also want to post a demo (https://stackblitz.com/)

Answer (score 0):

As it was already described here you should add `AppComponent` to `declarations` and `bootstrap` array inside of `AppModule`

```
@NgModule({
  declarations : [AppComponent],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  imports: [...]
})
```

You are also using `authentication` property inside of `*ngIf` in `app.component.html` but this property is not defined inside of `app.component.ts`

Try to add it to the `app.component.ts`

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'new-app';
  authentication = true;
}
```

This actually didn't cause any error message in console when I tested it on Stackblitz

It's also described in the tutorial you provided

> Basically we will have an authentication property in the component
>   which will allow us to remove the header and the menu if the user is
>   not logged in, and instead, show a simple login page.